# Having problem with simple if/else statement - python

Tags: python, if-statement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0aPM.png)

Having problem with simple if/else statement. Can't find where the problem is :(

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you print the top100?

Comment: Checking `x in pandas_series` looks for `x` in the index of the series, and not its values.  You can try using `song_input in top_100.song_name.values` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your code and list are like this. you will get the correct answer:

```
input = str(input("song name: ")) #stay
top100 = {
    "song_name":['song1', 'song2', 'song3', 'stay']
}
if input in top100['song_name']:
    print(f'I recommends {input}' )
else:
    prin("Not there")
```

#Output -> I recommends stay